# How to handle c# WPF thread in MVVM view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I am having a bear of a time figuring out how to handle a Thread from a class outside my ViewModel.

The Thread originates from a `Track` class. Here is the `ResponseEventHandler` code in `Track`:

```
public delegate void ResponseEventHandler(AbstractResponse response);
public event ResponseEventHandler OnResponseEvent;
```

When a "command" method is processed from within my `Track` object, the following code runs the `OnResponseEvent`, which sends a message in a Thread back to my ViewModel:

```
if (OnResponseEvent != null)
{
    OnResponseEvent(GetResponseFromCurrentBuffer());
}
```

`GetResponseFromCurrentBuffer()` merely returns a message type which is a pre-defined type within the `Track`.

My `MainWindowViewModel` constructor creates an event handler for the `OnResponseEvent` from the `Track`:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Track _Track = new Track();

    _Track.OnResponseEvent +=
        new Track.ResponseEventHandler(UpdateTrackResponseWindow);
}
```

So, the idea is that every time I have a new message coming from the `OnResponseEvent` Thread, I run the `UpdateTrackResponseWindow()` method.  This method will append a new message string to an `ObservableCollection<string>` list property called `TrackResponseMessage`:

```
private void UpdateTrackResponseWindow(AbstractResponse message)
{
    TrackResponseMessage.Add(FormatMessageResponseToString(message));
}
```

The `FormatMessageResponseToString()` method merely compares the message with all pre-defined message types within the `Track`, and does some nifty string formatting.

The main problem is:  **The UI disappears when `TrackResponseMessage.Add()` is run**. The executable is still running in the background, and the only way to end the task is to shut down Visual Studio 2010.

`TrackResponseMessage` is a public property within my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<String> TrackResponseMessage
{
    get { return _trackResponseMessage; }
    set
    {
        _trackResponseMessage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("TrackResponseMessage");
    }
}
```

Is there a need for me to marshal the `Thread` coming from the `Track` object to my ViewModel? Any example code would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a need for me to marshall the thread comming from the Track.cs object to my viewmodel? Any example code would be very appreciated!

Yes.  Unfortunately, while `INotifyPropertyChanged` will handle events from other threads, `INotifyCollectionChanged` does not (ie: `ObservableCollection<T>`).  As such, you need to marshal back to the VM.

If the VM is being create from the View (View-First MVVM) or is known to be created on the UI thread, there's a good option using .NET 4 tasks:

```
TaskScheduler uiScheduler;
public MainWindowViewModel() 
{
    uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Track _Track = new Track();
    _Track.OnResponseEvent += new Track.ResponseEventHandler(UpdateTrackResponseWindow);
}
```

Then, later, your event handler can do:

```
private void UpdateTrackResponseWindow(AbstractResponse message) 
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
       () => TrackResponseMessage.Add(FormatMessageResponseToString(message)),
       CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None,
       uiScheduler); 
}
```

This has the nice advantage of not pulling WPF or Silverlight specific resources and types into your ViewModel class (ie: `Dispatcher`), while still providing all of the benefits.  It also works, unchanged, in other routines with thread affinity (ie: WCF service work).

Comment: Yeeehaw!!  It worked great!  Reed, I owe you a donut!  You saved me hours of reading .net threading documentation.  The TaskScheduler makes it easy to read incomming threads from other class objects in my viewmodel.

Comment: @EnLaCucha: FYI - This only works for threads that have a SynchronizationContext installed.  That's true for WPF's main thread, WinForms's main thread, and WCF service calls, though.

Comment: With .net 4.5 you can now edit collections from another thread using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh140164(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the RaisePropertychanged is executed on a thread other than the UI thread AND the event handler for the event touches the UI you need to switch to the UI thread.